# android ListView selected item

Tags: android

how can i select an item (Text) from an ListVIew?

ps:I am new on Android Development

Comment: you want to get text from list view items ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Its hard to tell what you are asking based on your current question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are confused on how to get the text from selected item , then you should use listview.setOnItemClickListener,

You should go through this example if you have not before.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: If it helped and solved your problem , you can tick the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

In list view listener you use that example

```
 // ListView Item Click Listener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {

                   // ListView Clicked item index
                   int itemPosition     = position;

                   // ListView Clicked item value
                   String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    // Show Alert 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                      "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .show();

                  }

             });
```

http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90